# What's the meaning of "the big sort"?

Tags: definition

I'm listening to Brene Brown's podcast. The word "big sort" comes up, and i've tried to search for meaning on the internet but there was no definition :'(

Can you please explain it to me?

Comment: Hi. Can you give a complete sentence in which 'big sort' is used?

Comment: Thank you for replying to my question.
Here is the full text which "the big sort" is used:
"I’m going to take individuals and groups of people on their own terms and not make assumptions ahead of time about whether or not I can connect with them over their values. I think that’s become more difficult today. And the reason is partly, I describe in the book, and this is a phrase that other writers coined and have used, it’s not original to me, we’ve gone through what’s been called the big sort."

Answer (score 0):

I'd never heard the expression, but I googled *big sort* and found [this](https://www.hoover.org/research/myth-big-sort).

*Sort* here seems to mean 'an act of sorting' (dividing a collection of things into different sorts) rather than the usual meaning of *kind.*